# Building reusable image libraries for JAutomate (a GUI Testing tool)

Tags: automated-testing, image-based-testing

I am a new tester and I am working with [JAutomate](http://jautomate.com/).

I find it annoying to keep taking new pictures for every new recording you do in the tool and in the end it will also take a lot of memory space. So I wonder if any of you out there has experiences with this tool and maybe has knowledge about how to reuse Imagen of the same objects so that you don´t end up with a zillion pictures of the same Save button for example.

So in short I wish to create some kind of pictures library and be able to connect my scripts with this library so that I can reuse pictures and save memory space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the manual? http://jautomate.com/wp-content/uploads/JAutomateManual.pdf

Chapter 11 writes about all kind of libraries, including an image library.

> **11.3. Image Library** Place reusable images in the Image Library. Images in the Image Library can be easily  and quickly inserted into any
>   script. Use the Add to Image Library menu option to add  new images to
>   the library. You may also copy/paste steps from any script into the
>   Image  Library.

I think you are on the right track. You only want one image per button/element in the application. If the style of the application changes you do not want to update a zillion images. Also you don't want to repeat the same combination of steps in a row. Make sure you also use the described steps library for any steps you repeat over and over again.

Since its a commercial product, I would [contact support](http://jautomate.com/contact/) for extra training or pointers about how to use the image library.